# Springboot endpoint submitted with fetch redirects to login page

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Trying to submit a form to the /policy-holder page using fetch in js but the endpoint redirect to the login page, users are not expected to login only admins. What might be causing this issue and how can I fix it. I have tried adding permitted all to the security config for the endpoint and no luck. Also basic auth doesn't work at  the same time as cookie auth, how can I fix this

```
  @PostMapping("/policy-holder")
    public ResponseEntity<PolicyHolder> createPolicyAndBeneficiaries(@RequestBody @Validated PolicyHolderRequestDto policyHolderDto) {
        return policyHolderService.createPolicyAndBeneficiaries(policyHolderDto);
    }
```

Service.

```
 @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<PolicyHolder> createPolicyAndBeneficiaries(PolicyHolderRequestDto policyHolderDto) {
        paymentGateway.verifyAccount(policyHolderDto.accountNumber(), "050");

        PolicyHolder ph =  PolicyHolder.builder()
                .accountNumber(policyHolderDto.accountNumber())
                .phoneNumber(policyHolderDto.phoneNumber())
                .lastName(policyHolderDto.lastName())
                .firstName(policyHolderDto.firstName())
                .email(policyHolderDto.email())
                .build();

        PolicyHolder savedPolicyHolder = policyHolderRepository.save(ph);
```

Security

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers("/register/**","/css/**","/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/index").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/policy-holder").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/users","/send").hasRole("ADMIN")
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                ).formLogin(
                        form -> form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
                                .permitAll()
                ).logout(
                        logout -> logout
                                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                                .permitAll()
                );

        return http.build();
    }
```

js

```
fetch('/policy-holder', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(extractedData),
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log('POST request response:', data);
            // Handle the response data as needed
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error making POST request:', error);
            // Handle the error
        });
```

Comment: Could be related to csrf as you don't pass the token anywhere, try setting logging to trace for `org.springframework.web`, also see similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74421330/crnk-spring-security-only-get-request-work

Comment: What is the path of the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change in spring security, /error route is no longer exempt from auth. When there is an error spring tries to visit the route and redirects to the login page hence the issue adding below fixed the login error for me. Still had to fix the underlying issue though

```
.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
```